# Is $\frac{a+b}{c+d}<\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{d}?$, for $a,b,c,d>0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Is $$\frac{a+b}{c+d}<\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{d}$$
for $a,b,c,d>0$

If it is true, then can we generalize?

EDIT:typing mistake corrected.

EDIT, WILL JAGY. Apparently the **real question** is 
Is $$\color{magenta}{\frac{a+b}{c+d}<\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{d}}$$
for $a,b,c,d>0,$ where letters on the left hand side and in the **numerator** stay in the **numerator** on the right-hand side, and letters on the left hand side and in the **denominator** stay in the **denominator** on the right-hand side.

Comment: Have you tried checking it for some values, e.g. $a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4$?

Comment: Or a = b = c = d = 1...

Comment: Daniel: it was typing mistake

Comment: You will find your answer here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics)

Comment: I don't have any other realtions on a,b,c,d

Comment: @Thomas, the version of the inequality in the title and first line moves the letter $b$ from the numerator to the denominator. That is not how the mediant works. It also moves $c$ from the denominator to the numerator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you consider them as slopes, then $(0,0)$, $(b,a)$, $(d,c)$ and $(b+d,a+c)$ form a parallelogram. So the slope of the line between $(0,0)$ and $(b+d,a+c)$ will be between the slopes of the lines between $(0,0)$ and $(b,a)$ and $(d,c)$. That means that $\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ will be between $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$. Since these two are positive, this means that $$\frac{a+c}{b+d}\leq \max\left(\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d}\right)< \frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}$$

It's pretty clear that you can generalize this by induction to:

$$\frac{a_1+\dots+a_n}{b_1+\dots+b_n}\leq \max_i\left(\frac{a_i}{b_i}\right)$$

Comment: @Phani, notice that what you typed in your title is completely unrelated to what Thomas answered. Clearly, since you accepted it, this is what you meant. Learn to proofread what you post, including the title!!!

Comment: I edited in a mediant version of the question in magenta.

Comment: @WillJagy yes, I didn't read carefully, assume it was the simple and obvious question.

Comment: I read the math symbols very carefully for up to two  lines, if there is more than that I go look for other questions. I mostly ignore the words.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different approach:

Multiply both sides by (c+d), which we can do without altering the inequality because c and d are positive:

$$ a+b < \frac{a(c+d)}{c} +\frac{b(c+d)}{d}$$
$$ a+b < \frac{ac}{c} +\frac{ad}{c} +\frac{bc}{d} +\frac{bd}{d}$$
$$ a+b < a + \frac{ad}{c} +\frac{bc}{d} +b$$
$$ a+b < a+b +\frac{ad}{c}+\frac{bc}{d}$$
$$ \frac{ad}{c} +\frac{bc}{d} > 0$$

This is clearly always true because both terms must be > 0.

This same basic outline works for a 3 term version of this:
$$\frac{a+b+c}{d+e+f} < \frac{a}{d}+\frac{b}{e} +\frac{c}{f}$$

and will clearly work for any number of terms because after multiplying by the denominator on the left hand side, you will always spit out on the right hand side, exactly the left hand side numerator plus some additional terms which must be positive.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=\lambda c$ and $b=\mu d$, where $\lambda, \mu>0$.
$$\frac {a+b}{c+d}=\frac {\lambda c+\mu d}{c+d}=\frac {\lambda (c+d)+\mu (c+d)-(\lambda d+\mu c)}{c+d}=\lambda + \mu -\frac {\lambda d+\mu c}{c+d}<\lambda + \mu = \frac ac+\frac bd
$$